# display the unicode value in the java screen

Tags: java

how to display non english words with unicode in java?

"\u0905\u092E\u0940\u0924\u093E\u092A" i have to display this ib Hindi?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you really want to know is "Where do I get a font with Hindi characters that I can use in Java?"

Comment: or perhaps you want Swing/AWT?

Comment: It would indeed be more clear if you elaborate *where* you want to display it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just have it in a String and display it. You only need to use the proper encoding in the display component/console. `UTF-8` should suffice.

```
System.out.println("\u0905\u092E\u0940\u0924\u093E\u092A");
```

This prints अमीताप in my Eclipse environment which is configured to use `UTF-8` in its console.

**Edit**: this ain't going to work in for example the Windows command console, because it by default doesn't use `UTF-8` nor has a font which covers those codepoints. If you're actually using Eclipse, then you can set the Workspace encoding in its preferences by *General* > *Workspace* > *Text file encoding*.

Further on, anywhere where an Java API can take the character encoding as extra argument, then you need to make use of it and set it to `UTF-8`. Otherwise the platform default encoding will be used, which may be `ISO-8859-1` or `cp1252`, which is incorrect for those characters. If you for example want to write this String to some `OutputStream`, then you need to construct an `OutputStreamWriter` where in you pass `UTF-8` as 2nd constructor argument. You may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) useful as well.

Comment: I have a similar doubt and I followed the steps mentioned in your blog. Can you please help? Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772275/utf-8-text-hindi-not-getting-displayed-on-browser-window-or-eclipse-console