# How to display kannada text string in java applications

Tags: java, user-interface, text, applet

I am having an applet in Java application, in which I want to display kannada text in the text area using text box. please help me with how to do it ?

Comment: *"so i want one simple program"*  Simple usually boils down to 'hire someone that has achieved it before'.   BTW - do you have a (specific) question, or should we just interpret the question as 'Can u giv me teh codez?'?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340739/setting-unicode-characters-in-java-frames

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the character encoding using [unicode](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unicode.html), For **Kannada** *it's range from* **0C80 to 0CFF**.
Check this [PDF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0C80.pdf) for further details.
Java unicode example applet is available [here](http://www.pccl.demon.co.uk/java/unicode.html)
Below **Examples** help you to understand better:
[setting-unicode-characters-in-java-frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340739/setting-unicode-characters-in-java-frames)
[display-the-unicode-value-in-the-java-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799458/display-the-unicode-value-in-the-java-screen)