# Get Hindi data from Apache CouchDB 1.6.1

Tags: java, gwt, couchdb

I am using  **Apache CouchDB 1.6.1** as my database. We are creating quiz and saving the question data in couchdb. Now, there are users who want to create question in hindi. Data gets  saved in couchdb easily but on retrieval of the data from couchdb its get converted into some absurd font. May be there is some issue with the font family and all I am unaware of all this.

We are using **Java** with **Gwt** in our project.

[image: COuchdb Sample Db Img]

[image: Data On fetching]

```
 public String getData(){
        Session session = new Session("192.168.1.70", 5984);
        String hindiresult=null;
        try{
            Database test = session.getDatabase("test");
            Document testdoc = test.getDocument("testdoc");
            hindiresult=testdoc.getString("hindifield");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hindiresult;
    }
}
```

This is our server side code fetching data here and returning it to client on alert. The Image I have already shared.
[image: Jar Using]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use utf-8 encoding, to support hindi.

Comment: Sorry but don't have idea about that, I will search for it Still If you can help how we do this on couchdb.

Comment: couchdb seems to be fine, you need to do it in your front-end side or paste the code, how u getting data from couchdb.

Comment: I have added the server side code and also the jar I am using. I am using currently java 1.8

Comment: there must be some way by which you can specify the encoding while retrieving the data from couchDB. i did it long back and you can do google for that, or have some work-around to convert the string in utf-8.

Comment: sir, sorry but didnt got anything still working on it

Comment: @Vartika , Please avoid using sir , also let me us know what all are u trying

Comment: Actually i have no idea about these encodings. So just searching

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141427/discussion-between-amitk-and-vartika).

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the encoding of the Eclipse Ide suggested in the following question from default to utf-8. [HELPFUL LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772275/utf-8-text-hindi-not-getting-displayed-on-browser-window-or-eclipse-console)